# Getting an exception while running popen on a command

Tags: python

I am running into the following error ,when running  Popen on command as below,if I try the command manually it works,
am not sure what is wrong here?can anyone give pointers on what is wrong here?

ERROR:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 164, in main
buildpipe = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

CODE:-

```
cmd = 'source build/envsetup.sh && lunch %s-userdebug && make -j32 2>&1 | tee build.log'% (target)

buildpipe = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) 
(output, error) = buildpipe.communicate()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`source` is a shell command. It's not an executable. When `Popen` tries to find the program, it runs into `OSError: No such file or directory`.

Maybe the `shell = True` flag can help, but try using `. env` instead of `source env`. It's the same command, but the `source` alias for `.` is not supported in some shells (like plain `sh`).

It doesn't *quite* make sense to use `source` in a `subprocess` call. If you want to run `python` from within a `virtualenv`, you can directly call the environment's local `python` executable:

```
Popen('path/to/env/bin/python', ...)
```